# Обрезка фоновой картинки

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите. Поставил картинку фоном. При уменьшении экрана картинка должна сохранять пропорции и  по высоте равняться высоте "header-section" а лишнее справа обрезаться и не отображаться.
Объясните пожалуйста.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
}

/*-------------------------------------- header ---------------------------- */
.header-menu-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.header-section {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    padding: 30px 0 90px ;  
}
.header-section .img-bg{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: .1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.header-section .menu ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header-section .menu ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #191919;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header-section .menu ul a:hover {
    color: #10c9c3;  
}
.header-section .menu ul a.active{
    color: #10c9c3;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}
.caption-header {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.caption-header h1{
    color: #1d1d1d;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 48px;
}
.caption-header p{
    color: #787878;
    font-family: "Nunito Sans";
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 25px 0;
}
.caption-header-row {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.caption-header-row a{
    padding: 20px 40px;
    background-color: #10c9c3;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 84px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
.caption-header-row a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }
    .caption-header-row {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .header-menu-col {
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .caption-header {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 568px) {
    .header-section .img-bg{
        
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
/*-------------------------------------- /header ---------------------------- */
/*-------------------------------------- about ---------------------------- */
.about-section {
    padding: 50px 0; 
    text-align: center;  
    
}
.about-section h1 {
    color: #191919;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.about-section p {
    color: #787878;
    font-family: "Nunito Sans";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 25px 0;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .about-section p {
        font-size: 14px;
}
/*-------------------------------------- /about ---------------------------- */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1"  content="width=device-width"> 
         <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
  
</head>
   <body>
        <div id="header" class="header-section">
          <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/eG0rvc/header_bg.jpg" alt="header_bg" border="0" class="img-bg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xl-12 header-menu-col">
                <div class="logo">
                  <a href="#"><img src="image/logo.png" width="31px" height="25px" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                  <ul>
                      <li class="menu-item"><a  class="active" href="#home">home</a></li>
                      <li class="menu-item"><a  href="#about">about</a></li>
                      <li class="menu-item"><a  href="#work">work</a></li>
                      <li class="menu-item"><a  href="#process">process</a></li>
                      <li class="menu-item"><a  href="#services">services</a></li>
                      <li class="menu-item"><a  href="#testcontact">testcontact</a></li>
                      <li class="menu-item"><a  href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!-- /============================= /menu =========================== !-->
              </div><!-- /============================= /col logo =========================== !-->
            </div>
            <div class="row caption-header-row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="caption-header">
                  <h1>We Design and Develop</h1>
                  <p>We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 
                      20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two 
                      about designing websites and mobile apps.</p>
                  <a href="#">contact us</a>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /============================= /col menu =========================== !-->
            </div><!-- /============================= /row =========================== !-->
          </div><!-- /============================= /container =========================== !-->
        </div><!-- /============================= /header-section =========================== !-->
        <div id="about" class="about-section">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                  <div class="caption-about">
                    <h1>Abous us</h1>
                    <p>Divide have don't man wherein air fourth. Own itself make have night won't make.<br> 
                        A you under Seed appear which good give. Own give air without fowl moveth dry first<br>
                        heaven fruit, dominion she'd won't very all.</p>
                    <img src="image/signature.png" alt="about us">
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /============================= /col  =========================== !-->
              </div><!-- /============================= /row =========================== !-->
            </div><!-- /============================= /container =========================== !-->
        </div><!-- /============================= /about-section =========================== !-->       
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в стили:

```
.header-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.header-section .img-bg {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
  * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}


/*-------------------------------------- header ---------------------------- */

.header-menu-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.header-section {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 30px 0 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.header-section .img-bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: .1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-section .menu ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header-section .menu ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #191919;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-section .menu ul a:hover {
  color: #10c9c3;
}

.header-section .menu ul a.active {
  color: #10c9c3;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}

.caption-header {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.caption-header h1 {
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.caption-header p {
  color: #787878;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.caption-header-row {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.caption-header-row a {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background-color: #10c9c3;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 84px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.caption-header-row a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .caption-header-row {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .header-menu-col {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .caption-header {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 568px) {
  .header-section .img-bg {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}


/*-------------------------------------- /header ---------------------------- */


/*-------------------------------------- about ---------------------------- */

.about-section {
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-section h1 {
  color: #191919;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.about-section p {
  color: #787878;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .about-section p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  /*-------------------------------------- /about ---------------------------- */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="header" class="header-section">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/eG0rvc/header_bg.jpg" alt="header_bg" border="0" class="img-bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 header-menu-col">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="image/logo.png" width="31px" height="25px" alt="logo"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li class="menu-item"><a class="active" href="#home">home</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#work">work</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#process">process</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#services">services</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#testcontact">testcontact</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /============================= /menu =========================== !-->
        </div>
        <!-- /============================= /col logo =========================== !-->
      </div>
      <div class="row caption-header-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="caption-header">
            <h1>We Design and Develop</h1>
            <p>We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.</p>
            <a href="#">contact us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /============================= /col menu =========================== !-->
      </div>
      <!-- /============================= /row =========================== !-->
    </div>
    <!-- /============================= /container =========================== !-->
  </div>
  <!-- /============================= /header-section =========================== !-->
  <div id="about" class="about-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="caption-about">
            <h1>Abous us</h1>
            <p>Divide have don't man wherein air fourth. Own itself make have night won't make.<br> A you under Seed appear which good give. Own give air without fowl moveth dry first<br> heaven fruit, dominion she'd won't very all.</p>
            <img src="image/signature.png" alt="about us">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /============================= /col  =========================== !-->
      </div>
      <!-- /============================= /row =========================== !-->
    </div>
    <!-- /============================= /container =========================== !-->
  </div>
  <!-- /============================= /about-section =========================== !-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```